# Is there a way to get the Tortoisehg repository explorer to start from a command prompt?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Is there a way to get the Tortoisehg repository explorer to start from a command prompt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just run `hgtk log`.